# How can a cv joint break suddenly?

Tags: suspension, cv-joint

I know that before a cv joint totally breaks, it produces sounds when turning.
I had nothing no wierd sounds, then suddenly i felt the driving wheel turns right hardly when I was about 70 km /h.

I fought the wheel for a while with no sounds at turning, then I heared two hard sounds and the wheel became good..

Then, joint made clicker sound on turns.. As soon as I went my neighborhood, the sounds was high even with going straight forward and the car stopped and found 4 out of 6 thr internal spheres of the joint..

This is a strange for me  there was no preceding alerts or anything at all.. Even the mechanic was surprised when I told him.

So how can a cv joint break suddenly?

Note : I am careful driver.

---

### EDIT 1

The vehicle is Fiat 128 - model 2006 - 1300 CC.
It has only 75 thousand kilo meters in 10 years ( as far as I know this is small )

Comment: So, rare but does happen - some cv joints can make noise for months and still continue working. Sadly you were unlucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many times a CV boot can be torn or cracked without anyone knowing. This can allowing dirt and moisture into the joint which can cause excessive wear, binding, corrosion and premature failure.

Yes, clicking is a common indicator, but sometimes, they just get worn to the point they bind up, then let go. And they can also just simply be defective.

You have not given us much detail about the vehicle, but I seriously doubt your driving had anything to do with the failure.

Comment: Question edited, I added the vehicle details..
If there are more details I can give, I'd be glad ..

Answer (score 1):

The local Deities weren't smiling on you, but these things happen.

My advice is that when you get that CV joint fixed (or entire axle replaced), you should do the other side also. Yes, it's an extra expense, but then you won't be worrying about when the other CV joint will let go..